# How to use JS part of phonegap plugin after installing with CLI in 3.x ?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to upgrade an existing phonegap 2.x plugin to use with my project (phonegap 3.5). This is what the js part of my plugin.xml looks like

```
 <js-module src="www/att.js" name="att">
  <clobbers target="AttPlugin" />
</js-module>
```

I saw an example of how this js was used in the  phonegap 2.x version of this plugin. This is what the code in their sample application looked like

```
define([ "require", "exports", "module", "att" ], function(require, exports,
    module) {

/*
 * require att.js in 'phonegap' variable
 */

phonegap = require('att');

phonegap.ATT.authorize(accessKey, secretKey, scope, grantType);

});
```

In my code for my phonegap 3.5 application using the plugin.xml whose snippet i posted above this is what i am doing

```
AttPlugin.ATT.authorize(accessKey, secretKey, scope, grantType);
```

I get an error saying ATTPlugin is undefined . What am i doing wrong? 
Here is a link to the js file for reference--> [ATT.JS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzwe6b3fjpq3cac/att.js)

Comment: Have you included the JS plugin in your index.html file? Need to put the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="att.js"></script>` preferably in the head tag

Comment: @frank Phonegap 3.5 injects it into the HTML and i have verified this .It is in the head tag

Comment: How are you creating the AttPlugin variable? As per the sample, what you need to do is as follow  `AttPlugin = require('att');` and then use the variable for accessing the plugin APIs. Can you show your **complete** code as to how you have defined the AttPlugin variable?

Comment: @frank i am not too familiar with require. The one lined mentioned above is all i am using as i assumed that since i set the target to "AttPlugin" in my plugin.xml it would laod it into that variable.

Comment: Have you tried the `require` call as stated in my previous comment.